# probleme with bootstrap validator

Tags: bootstrapper, jquery-form-validator

the problem is if i fill the first input the second input highlight with green and if clear the first input the second input highlight with reed
 i try many solution with this script but i do not understand what is the problem

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

  <fieldset>
    <legend align="">Information Personnel</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label>Prénom</label>
                <input type="text" name="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label style="display:block; text-align: right;">الإسم</label>
                <input type="text" name="2" class="form-control keyboardInput"  placeholder="الإسم" style="text-align: right;">
            </div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and this the java-script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
        //container: '#messages',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            1: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Veuillez remplir votre nom'
                    }
                }
            },
            2: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Veuillez remplir votre hhhh'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put your fields one by one in a form group

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label>Prénom</label>
                <input type="text" name="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom">
            </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label style="display:block; text-align: right;">الإسم</label>
                <input type="text" name="2" class="form-control keyboardInput"  placeholder="الإسم" style="text-align: right;">
            </div>
    </div>
```